# Is eigenvector_centrality present in igraph 0.9.10?

Tags: python, igraph, xlwings

When looking for eigenvector_centrality in igraph 0.9.10 (the version I'm using) I couldn't find it:

https://igraph.org/python/api/0.9.10/

Then I've looked API reference for 0.9.8 and found it:

https://igraph.org/python/api/0.9.8/igraph._igraph.GraphBase.html#eigenvector_centrality

I'm trying to calculate Eigenvector centralities for some graphs and I'm getting the following message on Excel (using xlwings):

AttributeError: module 'igraph' has no attribute 'eigenvector_centrality'

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Always show the code you actually ran, not just the error that resulted from it. Presumably you tried to use `eigenvector_centrality` as a free function, however, it is actually a method of `Graph`.

Comment: You will find most of the functionality as methods of the `Graph` class. Thus if you are looking to see if some piece of network analysis technique is implemented in igraph, it's best to look at [Graph](https://igraph.org/python/api/latest/igraph.Graph.html) first. `eigenvector_centrality` is also found here.

Comment: This is what I tried:                                      
 EC=ig.eigenvector_centrality(G,directed=True, scale=True, weights=edges, return_eigenvalue=False, arpack_options=None)
 sht=xw.Book.caller().sheets['CENTR']
 sht.range('BS1').value=EC

Comment: As mentioned above, you need to call it as a method, not a free function. `G.eigenvector_centrality(...)`.

Comment: FYI, the name index has been re-added to the 0.9.10 documentation. It is live on the website now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.